# Latex pass expanded command

Tags: latex

I have the following usecase:

I can get strings via python

```
\newcommand{\lan}[1]{\pyc{print(lan_db['#1'])}}
\lan{STRING_TO_FORMAT}
```

Output: firstname: {} lastname: {}

Now i have a command to call the python format function

```
\newcommand{\format}[2]{\pyc{print('#1'.format(#2))}}
\format{firstname: {} lastname: {}}{'Jon','Doe'}
```

Output: firstname: Jon lastname: Doe

i want to call the format function like this:

```
\format{\lan{STRING_TO_FORMAT}}{\firstname,\lastname}
```

but the `\lan`, `\firname` and `\lastname` commands are not executed before passed to the format function.

i already researched that `\expandafter` may be the solution to my problem but aren't able to make it work

can someone help me here?

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Your problem is probably that you can't have fragile content as macro argument. There are several other approaches, which would be easy to show if your question would have a [mre]